# error 500 with cURL JSON PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

Expecting to pull the JSON objects from the '$array' cycliung through the 'foreach' and using cURL to post each time the current object of data.

Currently getting a error 500 and not entirely sure why.

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("/home/scott/sandbox/apitest/export.json");
$array = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($array as $group) {
    $Name = $group['Name'];
    $Position = $group['Position'];
    $Company = $group['Company'];
    $Description = $group['Description'];
    $Country = $group['Country'];
    $Zip = $group['Zip'];
    $City = $group['City'];
    $State = $group['State'];
    $Address = $group['Address'];
    $Email = $group['Email'];
    $Website = $group['Website'];
    $Phonenumber = $group['Phonenumber'];
    $CompanyNumber = $group['CompanyNumber'];
    $CompanyName = $group['CompanyName'];
    $RegAddressAddressLine1 = $group['RegAddressAddressLine1'];
    $RegAddressAddressLine2 = $group['RegAddressAddressLine2'];
    $RegAddressPostTown = $group['RegAddressPostTown'];
    $RegAddressCounty = $group['RegAddressCounty'];
    $RegAddressCountry = $group['RegAddressCountry'];
    $RegAddressPostCode = $group['RegAddressPostCode'];
    $CompanyCategory = $group['CompanyCategory'];
    $CompanyStatus = $group['CompanyStatus'];
    $CountryOfOrigin = $group['CountryOfOrigin'];
    $DissolutionDate = $group['DissolutionDate'];
    $IncorporationDate = $group['IncorporationDate'];
    $URI = $group['URI'];

$myobj = array(
    "data" => array(
        "Name" => $Name,
        "Position" => $Position,
        "Company" => $Company,
        "Description" => $Description,
        "Country" => $Country,
        "Zip" => $Zip,
        "City" => $City,
        "State" => $State,
        "Address" => $Address,
        "Email" => $Email,
        "Website" => $Website,
        "Phonenumber" => $Phonenumber,
        "CompanyNumber" => $CompanyNumber,
        "CompanyName" => $CompanyName,
        "RegAddressAdressLine1" => $RegAddressAdressLine1,
        "RegAddressAdressLine2" => $RegAddressAdressLine2,
        "RegAddressPostTown" => $RegAddressPostTown,
        "RegAddressCounty" => $RegAddressCounty,
        "RegAddressCountry" => $RegAddressCountry,
        "RegAddressPostCode" => $RegAddressPostCode,
        "CompanyCategory" => $CompanyCategory,
        "CompanyStatus" => $CompanyStatus,
        "CountryOfOrigin" => $CountryOfOrigin,
        "DissolutionDate" => $DissolutionDate,
        "IncorporationDate" => $IncorporationDate,
        "URI" => $URI
  )
);


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3001/derp/submission",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $myobj,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

// if ($err) {
//   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
// } else {
//   echo $response;
// }

}
?>
```

Comment: A 500 is a server side error - presumably an issue validating the input. I would first check the raw request sent to the server to verify the request is in the format intended, then check the server side logs to see what is failing.

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but you set cURL headers to be application/json, but the `$myobj` is a php array. Is your request data suppose to be `multipart/form-data` or `application/json`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $myobj,
```

with:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($myobj),
```

You are trying to send a PHP array to a server, with Content-Type header being application/json, so you should encode it to json.